# Can't use toString to display array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, null, tostring

getting the following error message when trying to use toString to display array:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomArray {

private int data[];
private int value;


        public RandomArray(int x)
        {
            Random gen = new Random();
            int[] data = new int[x];

            for (int index = 0; index<x; index ++)
                data[index] = gen.nextInt(x);

        }

        public String toString()
        {
            String output = "";
            for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
            {
                output +=data[i];
            }
            return output;
        }



     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int data;
        System.out.println("please enter the number of integers you would like to create an array for");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        RandomArray table = new RandomArray(x);

        table.toString();
```

From what I can tell this error means the toString is throwing null? But I do not know why that is, can anyone help me out?

Comment: If I change int[] data = new int[x]; to data = new int[x]; I get this error message:     error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int
      int data = new int[x];                                                                                                 error: array required, but int found
       data[index] = gen.nextInt(x);

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring your data array which is hiding the one you are filling.

```
 Random gen = new Random();
 int[] data = new int[x]; // remove the int[] declaration
```

Also, it might be easier if you just did the following:

```
// your toString method
public String toString() {
    return Arrays.toString(data);
}
```

In response to your question, you can do this.

```
int[] data; // you did this - leave it alone

// and later you should do this.

 public RandomArray(int x) {
     Random gen = new Random();
     data = new int[x]; // designated as an array above

     for (int index = 0; index<x; index ++)
         data[index] = gen.nextInt(x);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how we can remove the first [], according to my text book that absolutely has to be there. For example, double[] discounts = new double[35];

Comment: You did it at two locations.  The first statement in your code, and the location where I pointed to.  So leave the first one alone and later just do `data = new int[x];` If you don't do that, you are creating two separate arrays.  The one inside your constructor is local and will go out of scope when the constructor exits.

Comment: Ok, I've done that but now my toString doesn't return anything, the program just ends. As my nick states.. I'm a bit slow..

Comment: You can't just call table.toString().  It returns a string that needs to be printed. So try `System.out.println(table.toString())`.  And you're not slow.  Just new at this. You'll get it in no time.  In fact, all you  have to do is `System.out.println(table);`  The toString method will be called for your automatically.

Comment: Of course, that makes so much sense! I should have known to do that! And thank you for the words of encouragement, learning to code I find can be incredibly disheartening at times, so thank you again!